# Bokeh plot is deactivated when user clicks in DataTable, and there's no proper way to activate the plot

Tags: python, bokeh

When I use a DataTable in my bokeh application, the plots on my page become decativated whenever I click inside the datatable. This happens with `editable=True` and `editable=False`.

The only way that I found to activate the plot again is to click the "Reset" tool button.

Questions:

- Am I doing something wrong in my Bokeh app?
- Has anyone else encountered this, and found a workaround? (a Javascript workaround, perhaps?)

Screen shot (notice the deactivated color in the plot):

[image]

The complete bokeh app is below, run with `bokeh serve --show filename.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Button, DataTable, TableColumn, Paragraph
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DateFormatter, StringEditor
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure


def create_dataframe(number_of_series, number_of_values):
    t0 = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
    data = {
        "timestamp": [t0 + (i * timedelta(seconds=3600*2)) for i in range(number_of_values)]
    }
    data.update({
        "col{}".format(i): np.random.rand(number_of_values)
        for i in range(number_of_series)
    })
    return pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("timestamp")


source = ColumnDataSource(create_dataframe(10, 1000))


btn = Button(label="Click Me")


my_figure = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
my_figure.line(y="col0", x="timestamp", source=source)

data_table = DataTable(editable=True, source=source, columns=[
    TableColumn(title="Timestamp", field="timestamp", formatter=DateFormatter(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), editor=StringEditor()),
    TableColumn(title="col0", field="col0")
])

page_layout = layout([
    [widgetbox(Paragraph(text="Bokeh version: {}".format(bokeh.__version__)))],
    [widgetbox(btn), my_figure],
    [data_table]
])

curdoc().add_root(page_layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the intended behaviour behind using a bokeh ColumnDataSource. When you select a row in the table, that is registered in the data source selected attribute. see

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#columndatasource

You cant notice this at first because there are a large number of data points on the plot - any one isnt visible when selected.Try shift click and select multiple rows, and you will see segments of the plot turn dark blue - corresponding to those rows.

The simplest way to prevent the behaviour is to use seperate data sources.

If you wanted them to be the same, you would have to restore the source.selected dictionary each time it is updated, which seems pointless.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Button, DataTable, TableColumn, Paragraph
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DateFormatter, StringEditor
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure


def create_dataframe(number_of_series, number_of_values):
    t0 = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
    data = {
        "timestamp": [t0 + (i * timedelta(seconds=3600*2)) for i in range(number_of_values)]
    }
    data.update({
        "col{}".format(i): np.random.rand(number_of_values)
        for i in range(number_of_series)
    })
    return pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("timestamp")


source = ColumnDataSource(create_dataframe(10, 1000))

sourcetable = ColumnDataSource(create_dataframe(10, 1000))

btn = Button(label="Click Me")


my_figure = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
my_figure.line(y="col0", x="timestamp", source=source)

data_table = DataTable(editable=True, reorderable=False, source=sourcetable, columns=[
    TableColumn(title="Timestamp", field="timestamp", formatter=DateFormatter(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), editor=StringEditor()),
    TableColumn(title="col0", field="col0")
])

page_layout = layout([
    [widgetbox(Paragraph(text="Bokeh version: {}".format(bokeh.__version__)))],
    [widgetbox(btn), my_figure],
    [data_table]
])

curdoc().add_root(page_layout)
```

Comment: OK I see! Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, please accept the answer if that sufficiently answers your question.